# Total sum not working inside the for-each-group tag in BI Publisher when using Group Left

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-apps, xml-publisher, oracle-xml-publisher

I have the following template I am trying to upload-
[image]

[image]

This is giving me an output like -
[image]

This should come like -

[image]

How can i change the RTF template to get the desired output ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are referring to the output layout. The for-each and for-each-group functions can only be used for an entire line. The very first thing in the first cell needs to be the for-each, and the very last thing in the last cell needs to be the end for-each. You can have nested ones so there's multiple for-each in the first cell. The beginning for-each cannot be in column 2 or 3. An alternative is creating this with nested tables. They can look like one table if you make the margins /padding 0 in the correct spots.